# Affordable taxi service from BUF Airport to Niagara Falls on the Canadian side

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, niagara-falls, buffalo

I live in Washington DC and would like to go to Niagara Falls on the Canadian side. I am planning to buy a flight ticket and book a taxi, which can take me from BUF Airport to Niagara Falls on the Falls view. I looked at taxi companies but they all seem expensive.

Is there any other way to get a cheaper price than a taxi?

Comment: [Take a bus](https://www.google.com.sa/maps/dir/Niagara+Falls,+ON,+Canada/Buffalo+Niagara+International+Airport,+4200+Genesee+St,+Buffalo,+NY+14225,+United+States/@42.9863672,-79.04744,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x89d3445eec824db9:0x46d2c56156bda288!2m2!1d-79.0849436!2d43.0895577!1m5!1m1!1s0x89d374c8ccbe865d:0xc0e27200bdc16a88!2m2!1d-78.729507!2d42.939706!3e3?hl=en), should be much cheaper..

Comment: I doubt very much a taxi will take you across the border. To the border perhaps, but not across it.

Comment: @KateGregory Motor vehicles cross borders all the time. The cab website says they can transport someone in Canada.

Comment: Fyi I live in DC and would just drive the whole way to Niagara. It's maybe 7 hours each way, and you have your car. Flying into Buf will be pretty expensive.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there are some options in terms of ground transportation from Buffalo Airport, going to Niagara Falls on either the American or Canadian side:

- [taxis](http://buffaloairport.com/Ground/Shuttle.aspx) and shuttles like the company you found all seem to have fares around USD75 to Amaerican side, USD80-85 to Canadian side. [Some shuttle](http://www.buffaloairporttaxi.com/our-services) seems to be a bit cheaper, priced USD50 to the American side and USD65 to the Canadian side, with less flexibility in the times and probably drop-off places.
- Buses like [Megabus/Coach Canada](http://ca.megabus.com) have coaches going from Buffalo airport to Canadian-side Niagara Falls. The trip costs USD3 but it is happening only twice a day.
- [Public transit](http://buffaloairport.com/Ground/PublicTrans.aspx) options are available too, as @MeNoTalk suggested. Take either the [24](http://metro.nfta.com/Routes/pdfs/24.pdf) or [204](http://metro.nfta.com/Routes/pdfs/204.pdf) (express) from the airport to Buffalo downtown and then take the [40](http://metro.nfta.com/Routes/pdfs/40.pdf) or [60](http://metro.nfta.com/Routes/pdfs/60.pdf) (express) to Niagara Falls (US). A one-way ticket costs USD2, a day pass USD5. It does not go to the Canadian side, but I suppose you can take a cab or even walk (to be verified).